# Multiuser workspace Tricentis Tosca

Tags: automation, tosca

Does anyone have solution steps, where I can see how to work on multi user workspace which was created by another user in Tricentis Tosca.

Note: The workspace is stored in MS sql DB by another user, I want to work on same workspace.

I search a lot but not getting details steps.

Comment: i wonder how you did your search because this is described in tosca manual https://support-hub.tricentis.com/open?id=manual&path=%2Ftosca%2F1520%2Fen%2Fcontent%2Ftosca_commander%2Fcreate_workspace_multiuser.htm&product=tosca&sessionRotationTrigger=true&type=product_manual&version=15.2

Answer (score 0):

Before you can work on an object in a multi-user workspace it must be [checked out](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/tosca_commander/checkin_and_checkout.htm). You might look into taking the [Automation Specialist 1](https://academy.tricentis.com/automation-specialist-level-1) training class as I believe it has a section that covers checkin/checkout.